# prevent users from downloading music

Tags: asp.net

i have been writing a music website for my customer using ASP.NET. Everything has been cool except I don't know how to prevent the users from downloadng the song which is being played. For example, I click "Heal the world" to play and while the song is playing, I dont't want the IDM download manager or other download programs appear the download dialog

---

any help for my question?
I used this code to play the song

```
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" 
src="files/funring/15.mp3" align="absbottom" />
```

And I don't want the IDM download appears as shown in the followwing image [image]

Comment: Just get Lars Ulrich to moderate your site. Ooh. I went there...

Comment: Not sure if you can help it if you're playing back the song as a MP3 hosted on a HTTP server. Hosting music on a streaming media server might help though.

Comment: I think you're saying: when people click on the button, they see a download dialog, instead of hearing the music. Correct?

Comment: @David Relihan: what is Lars Ulrich?
@Mr Roys: not sure what you mean? :) 
@egrunin: that's right

Comment: Lars Ulrich is the drummer from Metallica, also of anti-napster legal crusade fame.

Answer (score 15):

`The song is being played===The song is being downloaded`

Get used to it.

**EDIT** *(A more useful answer)*

In all likelihood, in the case you describe, it's either a Flash Media Server/Red5/Wowza delivering audio as RTMP (yes, there are programs that can download these) or Windows Media and it's near inpenetrable DRM (and limited audience). Effectively the FMS route would be the one I would take were I shipping music to the browser and needed a good blend of max reach versus some level of obfuscation, however be aware that at the end of the day if it can be listened to, it can be copied.

Comment: Yes, that is true. There are software to record sound if the song is being played.

Comment: i used to surf a music website and they use a special player to play music. IDM couldn't even download it. I think it must have a solution

Comment: This isn't what he's asking, see his comment. He's probably linking to the file via <a href="file.mp3">, and the browser is offering to download rather than play in-place.

Comment: this is what I mean: 
I used this code to play the song "<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="files/funring/15.mp3" align="absbottom" />"

And I don't want the IDM download appears as shown in the followwing image
http://h.imagehost.org/0933/Untitled_13.png

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're putting links to the files on your webpage, something like this:

```
<a href="theSong.mp3">theSong</a>
```

This isn't what you want. Instead, you need an embedded player on the page.

**Edit** I did this myself just now. [Here's a working example on my website](http://www.grunin.com/eroica/?page=extremes.htm).

First, go to [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/mp3player/) and download their Flash player (my page uses the
    simplest one).

Next, put the .swf from that page on your website. Then on
    your page you put this:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player_mp3_1.0.0.swf" 
    width="200" height="30">
    <param name="movie" value="player_mp3_1.0.0.swf" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=media/theSong.mp3" />
</object>
```

**Notes**
1. Note that you have to put the name of the player's .swf file in *two* places.
2. Instead of theSong.mp3, put the actual location of the music file

Apparently there are lots of ways to customize the look of the player, but I didn't look for the documentation.

Comment: hi egrunin i tried your code but nothing happens. only the mp3_player appears
Here is my code
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
src="player_mp3.swf?audioUrl=files/funring/15.mp3" width="400px" height="50px"
allowscriptaccess="never" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" wmode="window"
flashvars="playerMode=embedded" />

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I think might help is to stream some kind of ENCRYPTED VERSION (or DRM protected version) of the song. Of course, you will need a special player for your songs that will contain the CRYPTO KEY (DRM decoder) to play the music.

If you stream MP3 or any other open formats, one way or the other, users will be able to download, store and play the music.

Comment: Again, I don't think this is what he's talking about. I'll try to come up with an answer...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the users to pay for the music offer a good service with reasonable prices and they will pay.

Preventing users to do something never works, there's always someone who finds a workaround. Actually, preventing users to do something presses them to find a workaround.

If something is played you can record it, no matter what "protection" it has. Even the most super-sofisticated protection cannot prevent the user to connect a cable from the audio output of their PC to an external recorder and burn it to a CD or use mplayer to do it.

Comment: If you downvote, please give an explanation about what is wrong with the answer. I don't care about the -1, as long as you explain it to me.

Comment: I guess the explanation would be that the question is not about preventing the users from downloading the music but the website itself to not present a button for that.